# Invalid command MDTM in iis ftp

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, rfc

I want to get all timestamp of files on ftp server.
It's an iis ftp server on windows 10.
When I typed "?" on command line prompt, lists below has shown

```
 ftp> ?
 Commands may be abbreviated.  Commands are:
 
 !               delete          literal         prompt          send
 ?               debug           ls              put             status
 append          dir             mdelete         pwd             trace
 ascii           disconnect      mdir            quit            type
 bell            get             mget            quote           user
 binary          glob            mkdir           recv            verbose
 bye             hash            mls             remotehelp
 cd              help            mput            rename
 close           lcd             open            rmdir
```

There is no mdtm command here, although google says this cmd was added in IIS6, IIS7 years ago.
What should I do?
Or is there any cmd can instead of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is the wrong command to use, as it prints out the help information about the Windows FTP command, not the IIS FTP server.

You should use `remotehelp`, and I wrote about that years ago in [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lexli/commands-supported-by-ftpwebrequest-and-iis-ftp).

Comment: I tried remotehelp, MDTM has been listed on the screen.
But, when I typed "MDTM a.txt" on command prompt, it shown "invalid command"

Comment: That's because you are in the FTP command context, so you cannot type FTP server verbs directly. Try `literal MDTM a.txt`.

Comment: Do you mean directly in command prompt without connecting to ftp?
C:\Users\chrisqwer\Documents>MDTM a.txt
'MDTM' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to try this in python to see if it works, Thank you Lex.

Comment: @ChrisQWER "in python"? Then it is far easier to use native Python FTP client support such as https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html Don't wrap over a command, as the Windows FTP command does not even support passive mode.